# Join 2 tables to get 2 related records Mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables like so:

```
# Match 
id, team1_id , team2_id
-----------------------
1, 10, 20
2, 10, 50



# Team 
id, team_name, team_country
---------------------------
10, team A , England
20, team B , France
```

I'm trying to get the list from Match table with both teams info, 
I wanna some thing like :

```
Team A (England)  vs Team B (France)
```

I tried this one, but I got false team info, some thing wrong with my query for sure.

Here's my query :

```
  SELECT `match`.*,
  `t1`.`team_country` as team1_country,
  `t2`.`team_country` as team2_country
  FROM `match`,
  `team` t1 , `team` t2
  WHERE `match`.`team1_id` = `t1`.`id` and `match`.`team2_id` = `t2`.`id`
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you show the output you obtain, and explain what's wrong with it?

Comment: Thanks for your replay eggyal, Actually I got wrong country names .. for example (Manchester United >> Spain) , while in the database I have (Manchester United >> England) and so on , but the list of match are ok. Team info are wrong.

Comment: The query you have shown above selects only the country name, not the team name.  So you must be doing something different to what you have shown us.

Comment: If I removed team2 info, and get only team1 info, I get it right , but only for the team1

Comment: Ignore the team name, let's say id > country_name for simplicity. I got id:10 > Country:Spain .. while in database I have id:10 > country:England in team table.

Comment: Sorry, eggyal. The query was  correct. the issue was in my database when I Imported thousands of team records, some of theme were missing and cause the issue :/

Answer (score 1):

I just fiddled it on my testmachine with postgres. The SQL shouldn't be different:

```
lara=# create table match ( id serial primary key, team1 int, team2 int);
CREATE TABLE
lara=# create table teams ( id serial primary key, name text, country text);
CREATE TABLE
lara=# insert into match(id, team1, team2) values (1,1,2),(2,1,3),(3,2,1);
INSERT 0 3
lara=# select * from match;
 id | team1 | team2
----+-------+-------
  1 |     1 |     2
  2 |     1 |     3
  3 |     2 |     1
(3 rows)

lara=# insert into teams values (1, 't1', 'en');
INSERT 0 1
lara=# insert into teams values (2, 't2', 'de');
INSERT 0 1
lara=# insert into teams values (3, 't3', 'fr');
INSERT 0 1
lara=# select * from match m left join teams t1 on t1.id=m.team1 left join teams t2 on t2.id=m.team2;
 id | team1 | team2 | id | name | country | id | name | country
----+-------+-------+----+------+---------+----+------+---------
  1 |     1 |     2 |  1 | t1   | en      |  2 | t2   | de
  2 |     1 |     3 |  1 | t1   | en      |  3 | t3   | fr
  3 |     2 |     1 |  2 | t2   | de      |  1 | t1   | en
```

So your actual query is correct. A cleaner one would be the following:

```
SELECT * FROM match m 
LEFT JOIN teams t1 ON t1.id=m.team1 
LEFT JOIN teams t2 ON t2.id=m.team2;
```

But your problem is obviously not the SQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot bloodstix, you are right, the problem wasn't from the query it was from the database records. I'll try you code, it way more cleaner. Thanks again